# How to parse xml data into list using react.js?

Tags: reactjs

I have data in xml. please help me in displaying the data as a list using react.js.

```
    <Item>
    <product product-id="638" is-retired="false">Auto</product>
    <product product-id="777" is-retired="true">test</product>
    +</Item>
```

thanks

Comment: Please share your data format as well as the code you have tried

Answer (score 0):

The DOMParser interface provides the ability to parse XML or HTML source code from a string into a DOM Document.

```js
const xmlString = `<Item>
    <product product-id="638" is-retired="false">Auto</product>
    <product product-id="777" is-retired="true">test</product>
    </Item>`;
const parser = new DOMParser();
const xml = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, 'text/xml');
console.log(xml.documentElement.textContent);
console.log(xml.getElementsByTagName('product')[0].getAttribute('product-id'));
```